# What is $HTHTH\left| 0 \right>$?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, bloch-sphere, hadamard

I'm currently going through [Introduction to Classical and Quantum Computing](https://www.thomaswong.net/introduction-to-classical-and-quantum-computing-1e3p.pdf), by Thomas Wong, and I'm struggling with exercise 2.33 (page 108):

> **Exercise 2.33.** Answer the following:
>
> (a) Calculate $HTHTH\left| 0 \right>$.

Given the two following transformations the Hadamard gate does:

$$\begin{align}
H\left| 0 \right> &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> + \left| 1 \right>)\\
H\left| 1 \right> &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> - \left| 1 \right>)
\end{align}$$

And the two following transformations the T gate does:

$$\begin{align}
T\left| 0 \right> &= \left| 0 \right>\\
T\left| 1 \right> &= e^{i\pi/4}\left| 1 \right>
\end{align}$$

I did the following:

$$\begin{align}
HTHTH\left| 0 \right> &= HTHT\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> + \left| 1 \right>) &\text{(apply H gate)}\\
&= HTH\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> + e^{i\pi/4}\left| 1 \right>) &\text{(apply T gate)}\\
&= HT\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> + \left| 1 \right>) + e^{i\pi/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> - \left| 1 \right>)) &\text{(apply H gate)}\\
&= H\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> + e^{i\pi/4}\left| 1 \right>) + e^{i\pi/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> - e^{i\pi/4}\left| 1 \right>)) &\text{(apply T gate)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| + \right> + e^{i\pi/4}\left| - \right>) + e^{i\pi/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| + \right> - e^{i\pi/4}\left| - \right>)) &\text{(apply H gate)}\\
&= \frac{1 + e^{i\pi/4}}{2}\left| + \right> + \frac{e^{i\pi/4} - i}{2}\left| - \right> &\text{(simplify)}\\
&= \frac{1 + e^{i\pi/4}}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> + \left| 1 \right>) + \frac{e^{i\pi/4} - i}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> - \left| 1 \right>) &\text{(change base)}\\
&= \frac{1 + e^{i\pi/4}}{2\sqrt{2}}\left| 0 \right> + \frac{1 + e^{i\pi/4}}{2\sqrt{2}}\left| 1 \right> + \frac{e^{i\pi/4} - i}{2\sqrt{2}}\left| 0 \right> - \frac{e^{i\pi/4} - i}{2\sqrt{2}}\left| 1 \right> &\text{(distribute)}\\
&= \frac{1 + 2e^{i\pi/4} - i}{2\sqrt{2}}\left| 0 \right> + \frac{1 + i}{2\sqrt{2}}\left| 1 \right>&\text{(simplify)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}[(1 - i + 2e^{i\pi/4})\left| 0 \right> + (1 + i)\left| 1 \right>]&\text{(simplify)}\\
\end{align}$$

However, the answer given at the back of the book (page 360) is (notice the $e^{i\pi/4}$ as opposed to $2e^{i\pi/4}$):
$$\begin{align}
HTHTH\left| 0 \right> &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}[(1 - i + e^{i\pi/4})\left| 0 \right> + (1 + i)\left| 1 \right>]\\
\end{align}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...
>
> $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}[(1 - i + 2e^{i\pi/4})\left| 0 \right> + (1 + i)\left| 1 \right>]$$
> ...
>
> However, the answer given at the back of the book (page 360) is (notice the $e^{i\pi/4}$ as opposed to $2e^{i\pi/4}$):
> $$\begin{align}
> HTHTH\left| 0 \right> &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}[(1 - i + e^{i\pi/4})\left| 0 \right> + (1 + i)\left| 1 \right>]\\
> \end{align}$$
>
> What am I doing wrong?

You seem to have done nothing wrong.

For notational convenience, I denote $T$ by
$$
T\equiv \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & t\end{matrix}\right)\;,
$$
where $t=e^{i\pi/4}$.

Then, by matrix multiplication:
$$
HTH = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{matrix}1+t & 1-t \\ 1-t & 1+t\end{matrix}\right)
$$
and
$$
THTH = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{matrix}1+t & 1-t \\ t-t^2 & t+t^2\end{matrix}\right)
$$
and
$$
HTHTH = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{matrix}1+2t-t^2 & 1+t^2 
\\ 1+t^2 & 1-2t-t^2\end{matrix}\right)
$$
and so
$$
HTHTH |0\rangle = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(
(1+2t-t^2)|0\rangle
+(1+t^2)|1\rangle
\right)\;,
$$
where, setting $t=e^{i\pi/4}$ and using $t^2 = i$, we see that:
$$
HTHTH |0\rangle = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(
(1+2e^{i\pi/4}-i)|0\rangle
+(1+i)|1\rangle
\right)\;.
$$

Comment: That makes sense, appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

I quickly computed in Mathematica. You are correct. The book is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: Good to know, will see if I can check my answers in Mathematica next time. Thanks for the tip!